# How to save data with Double quotes in Azure cosmos DB

Tags: azure, formatting, powerbi, double-quotes, export-csv

I am reading data from csv file . Part of the data contains quotation marks as 
`<"1", "02/12/2018", "How to save "Quotation" marks">`. After I read the data from csv I need to save it to a Azure CosmosDb collection using .Net code. The string -> How to save "Quotation" marks - gets retrieved in my code as:

> How to save \" Quotation\" marks.

I think that is how double quotes is persisted in .net as (\") , so that should be okay. However , when I am saving this data in azure cosmos db using bulk Import, the data is saved in Cosmos db in the same format as:

> How to save \"Quotation\" marks.

I want it to save it as:

> How to save "Quotation" marks.

How is this possible as Power BI report will be generated again from this data, so string should be properly formatted.

Comment: You could always just do an update of your entire table after you do the import to replace all occurrences of \" with ".  Probably not the ideal way, but depending on how big your dataset is, it could be a lot faster than figuring out how to fix the import.

Comment: I am getting error "Invalid string literal token" when running this query :SELECT n.Comment, n.Topic from c join n in c.Comments where contains(n.Comment, '\'). Using contains(n.Comment, '\"') is impossible , forcefully it tries to check contains(n.Comment, '\""')

Comment: I'm not sure what language you are writing your SELECT query in.  It doesn't look exactly like linq or t-sql.  I know Cosmos supports 4 different query types, and SQL is the only one I'm familiar with.  If you're querying in .NET like with linq, I think the problem is you need \\", since .NET interprets a \" as a single ", so you need two \\ to search for \ followed by ".  In SQL, something like this should work to bulk update every row in the table: UPDATE dbo.tablename
SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, '\"', '"');